# Pass parameter from azure devops pipeline yaml to cloudformation yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, tfs, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I do not manage to pass parameter from my azure yaml to my cloudformation yaml. I got the following error:

```
##[error]ValidationError: Parameters: [EnvironmentType] must have values
```

Nothing called "EnvironmentType" is passed  through azure yml to cloudformation yml.

**azure-pipeline.yaml**

```
pool:
  name: AWS

variables:
  ArtifactName: update-email

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build Stage
  ...

- stage: DeployToDev
  displayName: 'Deploy To Dev'
  variables:
    EnvironmentType: 'dev'
    AwsCredentials: '${{ variables.EnvironmentType }}-xx'
    AwsRegion: 'eu-central-1'
    CodeBucket: 's3-$(EnvironmentType)-xx'
    BucketPrefix: 'xx-$(ArtifactName)'
    StackName: 'clf-$(EnvironmentType)-xx'
  jobs:
  - job: DeployToDev
    steps:
    ...
    - task: AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools.CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack@1
      displayName: 'Create/Update Stack: $(StackName)'
      inputs:
        awsCredentials: ${{ variables.AwsCredentials }}
        regionName: $(AwsRegion)
        stackName: $(StackName)
        templateFile: '$(ArtifactName)/clf-xx-$(EnvironmentType).yml'
        parameters: |
          EnvironmentType=$(EnvironmentType)
```

**clf.yaml**

```
Parameters:
  EnvironmentType:
    Description: The deployment environment type.
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - prod

Resources:
  xx:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub "lbd-${EnvironmentType}-xx"
      ...
```

**What I also tried:**

```
- task: AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools.CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack@1
      displayName: 'Create/Update Stack: $(StackName)'
      inputs:
        awsCredentials: ${{ variables.AwsCredentials }}
        regionName: $(AwsRegion)
        stackName: $(StackName)
        templateFile: '$(ArtifactName)/clf-xx-$(EnvironmentType).yml'
        templateParameters: |
          - ParameterKey: EnvironmentType
            ParameterValue: ${{variables.EnvironmentType}}
```

- use "parameters"

  ```
   - task: AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools.CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack@1
     displayName: 'Create/Update Stack: $(StackName)'
     inputs:
       awsCredentials: ${{ variables.AwsCredentials }}
       regionName: $(AwsRegion)
       stackName: $(StackName)
       templateFile: '$(ArtifactName)/clf-xx-$(EnvironmentType).yml'
       parameters: |
         - ParameterKey: EnvironmentType
           ParameterValue: ${{variables.EnvironmentType}}
  ```
- Add templateParametersSource: inline and remove '/' in
  templateParameters
  got error `A sequence was not expected`, which point to the "ParameterKey" line

  ```
   - task: AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools.CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack@1
     displayName: 'Create/Update Stack: $(StackName)'
     inputs:
       awsCredentials: ${{ variables.AwsCredentials }}
       regionName: $(AwsRegion)
       stackName: $(StackName)
       templateFile: '$(ArtifactName)/clf-xx-$(EnvironmentType).yml'
       templateParametersSource: inline
       templateParameters: 
         - ParameterKey: EnvironmentType
           ParameterValue: 'dev'
  ```

I know that I can use ssm but here I am wondering if I want to stay with the solution using CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack task.

Am I missing anything here ? Is it possible to pass parameter from azure yml to cloudformation yml through CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack task ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to set "Template Parameters Source" to `inline` and then follow the correct format for the parameters, which is a list of objects each with `parameterKey` and `parameterValue`.  "`parameters: |`" the `|` is making yaml take that value as a multiline string.  that's not what you want; remove it.  Im looking at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/cloudformation-create-update.html#parameters

Comment: @erik258, tried to add inline and remove the mark after parameter, got another error: .../azure-pipeline-lbd-update-email.yml (Line: 97, Col: 11): A sequence was not expected

Comment: @erik258, this error point to "ParameterKey"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property "parameters" in "AWS CloudFormation Create/Update Stack task".

If want to pass parameters to your AWS template, you should set "Template Parameters Source" to inline as suggested by erik258. In addition you can also use template parameters file. For example:

```
parameters:
  deploymentEnvironment: ''         # development, staging, production, etc
  awsCredentials:        ''         # service connection name
  region:                ''         # the AWS region

steps:

- task: CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack@1
  displayName: 'Create/Update Stack: Staging-Deployment'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: '${{ parameters.awsCredentials }}'
    regionName:     '${{ parameters.region }}'
    stackName:      'my-stack-name'
    useChangeSet:   true
    changeSetName:  'my-stack-name-changeset'
    templateFile:   'my-aws-cloudformation-template.yml'
    templateParametersFile: '${{ parameters.deploymentEnvironment }}/parameters.json'
    captureStackOutputs: asVariables
    captureAsSecuredVars: false
```

You can see the detailed info from [Use Azure DevOps Parameters to Switch Between Your AWS Accounts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/use-the-aws-toolkit-for-azure-devops-to-automate-your-deployments-to-aws/#:%7E:text=Use%20Azure%20DevOps%20Parameters%20to%20Switch%20Between%20Your%20AWS%20Accounts).

---

Update

```
    templateParametersSource: inline
    templateParameters: |
      - ParameterKey: EnvironmentType
        ParameterValue: '$(EnvironmentType)'
```

Or

```
    templateParametersSource: 'inline'
    templateParameters: |
      [
        {
          "ParameterKey":"EnvironmentType",
          "ParameterValue":"$(EnvironmentType)"
        }
      ]
```

Comment: thanks for the example, if i want to stay inline: i tried to add inline and remove the mark after parameter, got another error: .../azure-pipeline-lbd-update-email.yml (Line: 97, Col: 11): A sequence was not expected, and it point to the line of "ParameterKey", do you have any idea ?

Comment: Keep the `|`after `templateParameters`, try what I shared above and see if it works.